# Extra blank pages in memoir when using \part

Tags: table-of-contents, parts, blank-page, letterspacing

Every now and then (seemingly with no pattern) the command \part and is calling extra blank pages in my document.  I used to be using

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,twoside,onecolumn,openright]{memoir}
```

but I have since converted to [oneside] and [openany] in order to suppress all blank pages.  However, this has not worked.

My MWE has two \part commands, both of which begin on recto pages (2 and 10), yet a blank page is produced as page 3, and text is produced on page 11.

Similarly, something else seems to be calling blank pages such as page 5.  Because of [openany], my Chapter 3 should begin right on page 5, but it is pushed to page 6 by a blank page.  The same thing occurs with Chapter 5 and page 8/9.

Further, when my MWE is changed to [twoside,openright] mode, it produces two blank pages after the first instance of \part.  \part prints on a recto page, the following verso and recto are blank, and then the following \chapter prints to a verso page for some reason, even though the document is still set to [openright]. In this case, I don't care about the blank verso page that is part of the \part command.  I'm wondering why there are suddenly two.

Rather than removing these extra blank pages manually, I would be much obliged if someone could tell me why they are being created and how to keep this from happening.

I'm not used to making MWEs (so mine is probably far from minimal) but here it is:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,oneside,onecolumn,openany]{memoir}
\frontmatter
\begin{document}

{\thispagestyle{empty}
\textsc{}\\[5cm]
\thispagestyle{empty}
\noindent \textit{\Huge Title:  \\Subtitle}
\textsc{}\\[0.5cm]
\indent \textbf{\textsc{\large Lorem Ipsum}}\\
\indent \textbf{\textsc{\large Lorem Ipsum}}\\
\indent \textbf{\textsc{\large Lorem Ipsum}}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Lorem Ipsum 1}
    \section{Lorem Ipsum}
        \subsection{Lorem Ipsum}
        \subsection{Lorem Ipsum}
    \section{Lorem Ipsum}
        \subsection{Lorem Ipsum}
        \subsection{Lorem Ipsum}
        \subsection{Lorem Ipsum}
    \section{Lorem Ipsum}

\part{Lorem Ipsum}
\chapter{Lorem Ipsum 2}
    \section{Lorem Ipsum}
        \subsection{Lorem Ipsum}
        \subsection{Lorem Ipsum}
        \subsection{Lorem Ipsum}
        \subsection{Lorem Ipsum}
    \section{Lorem Ipsum}
        \subsection{Lorem Ipsum}
        \subsection{Lorem Ipsum}
        \subsection{Lorem Ipsum}
        \subsection{Lorem Ipsum}
    \section{Lorem Ipsum}
        \subsection{Lorem Ipsum}
        \subsection{Lorem Ipsum}
        \subsection{Lorem Ipsum}
    \section{Lorem Ipsum}
        \subsection{Lorem Ipsum}
        \subsection{Lorem Ipsum}

\chapter{Lorem Ipsum 3}
    \section{Lorem Ipsum}
        \subsection{Lorem Ipsum}
        \subsection{Lorem Ipsum}
        \subsection{Lorem Ipsum}
        \subsection{Lorem Ipsum}
    \section{Lorem Ipsum}
        \subsection{Lorem Ipsum}
        \subsection{Lorem Ipsum}
        \subsection{Lorem Ipsum}
        \subsection{Lorem Ipsum}
    \section{Lorem Ipsum}
        \subsection{Lorem Ipsum}
        \subsection{Lorem Ipsum}
        \subsection{Lorem Ipsum}
    \section{Lorem Ipsum}
        \subsection{Lorem Ipsum}
        \subsection{Lorem Ipsum}

\chapter{Lorem Ipsum 4}
    \section{Lorem Ipsum}
        \subsection{Lorem Ipsum}
    \section{Lorem Ipsum}
    \section{Lorem Ipsum}
    \section{Lorem Ipsum}
    \section{Lorem Ipsum}

\chapter{Lorem Ipsum 5}
    \section{Lorem Ipsum}
        \subsection{Lorem Ipsum}
        \subsection{Lorem Ipsum}
        \subsection{Lorem Ipsum}
        \subsection{Lorem Ipsum}
    \section{Lorem Ipsum}
        \subsection{Lorem Ipsum}
        \subsection{Lorem Ipsum}
        \subsection{Lorem Ipsum}
        \subsection{Lorem Ipsum}
    \section{Lorem Ipsum}
        \subsection{Lorem Ipsum}
        \subsection{Lorem Ipsum}
        \subsection{Lorem Ipsum}
    \section{Lorem Ipsum}
        \subsection{Lorem Ipsum}
        \subsection{Lorem Ipsum}

\part{Lorem Ipsum}
\chapter{Lorem Ipsum 6}
    \section{Lorem Ipsum}
        \subsection{Lorem Ipsum}
    \section{Lorem Ipsum}
    \section{Lorem Ipsum}
    \section{Lorem Ipsum}
    \section{Lorem Ipsum}

\end{document}
```

Also, I am using TeXShop 3.73 for OSX Yosemite.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I am also using XeLaTeX. --JE

Comment: really you could reduce the example a lot more (you load several packages without using them) also you should try to show the problem with a generally available font (eg the default font) if you want people to be able to run the example and see the problem. Finally your example only has section headings and no text, as latex doesn't allow page breaks after a section there are no legal break points in the document other than forced breaks for chapters, so page breaking is likely to be odd in this example.

Comment: David -- Thanks.  Like I said I'm not used to doing this, so I didn't think of things like that.  I'll try to resubmit a better MWE later today.  Thanks!

Comment: John -- Doesn't work.  I still get blank pages.

Comment: David -- I just edited the MWE.  That should be able to run without any special packages or fonts.  I did not change the text, however.  Even though it is an atypical example, there should be some reason that \part inserts a blank page (now page 3 in the output) the first time it is used, but not the second, while being called in an [openany] environment.

If the environment is changed to [twoside,openright], the first instance of \part still calls two blank pages, forcing the next chapter to begin on a verso page, which should not happen in [openright].  I'm just trying to figure this out.

Comment: At least in your current MWE, the phenomen you observe seems to be an artefact of not having any regular content between the section commands.  Add `\usepackage{blindtext}` and add `\blindtext` after each `\chapter` and `\section`. Can you still reproduce the problem?
BTW, you have an opening brace that is never closed (right after `\begin{document}`), and you have two `\thispagestyle{empty}` commands on your titlepage.

Comment: Gernot -- That seems to fix the problem.  I've had this issue happen once before in a document that had quite a bit of content (too much for me to consider reducing to a MWE), so I assumed this was a similar problem.  If I can reproduce the issue despite using blindtext, I'll let you guys know.  Thanks!

Comment: as I warned before you made an example that I could run, having a sequence of section headings makes the document infeasible. TeX does scream at you `Overfull \vbox (106.58337pt too high) has occurred while \output is active` after such warnings you are lucky if blank pages are the most serious problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `\openany`, `\openright` and `\openleft` commands:

```latex
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}

\openany
\appendix

\openright
\appendixpage
This is the appendix.

\end{document}
```